# ngspice - print numbers in engineering notation

Tags: ngspice

Can `.print` in ngspice be told to print numbers in engineering notation (e.g. `vout = 450e-3`, not `vout = 4.5e-1`)? I've searched online and in the manual but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, it can't (but I'd like to be proved wrong), and I also can't find anything in the manual. I suspect it's because the underlying function is still C's `printf()`, which has no engineering format (I'm not talking about custom made formats).